# How to print line number that contains specific number?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have 6000 lines,with one per number float.

My code

```
awk '5.400000e+03 {print $0}' base.txt
```

Only prints numbers

```
5.400000e+03
5.400000e+03
5.400000e+03
5.400000e+03
5.400000e+03
5.400000e+03
5.400000e+03
5.400000e+03
5.400000e+03
5.400000e+03
5.400000e+03
5.400000e+03
```

I have changed to

```
awk '{if($0=="5.400000e+03 ") print NR}' base.txt
```

but then got nothing!
What should I try?

Comment: There is a space in the string in your command, but not in your file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
awk '$1 == "5.400000e+03" {print NR, $0}' base.txt
```

`$1` will always match first column irrespective of spaces or no spaces after shown data in your question. Use `print NR, $0` to print each record prefixed with record number.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use grep:

```
# just the line number
grep -wn "5.400000e+03" base.txt | cut -d: -f1
# both
grep -wn "5.400000e+03" base.txt
```

Comment: Actually that's a typical `grep` job. Good answer!

Comment: So you don't match something like `15.400000e+03`, use an anchor: `grep -n '^5.400000e+03'`. Or use non-regex matching: `grep -Fw '5.400000e+03'`